# Multiple developers on same individual iTunes account

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have an Apples `Individual` Developer account.

Now I have one more developer to assist me.
I have added him as my `Team admin` from iTunes Connect.

When he pulled the Xcode project, there is an error saying "No matching provisioning profiles found" in `General > Identity`.

Why cant he compile the project even though I have added him as a team admin?
Also can he submit the build to iTunes connect?

---

Image below clearly states that team admin can `Create Apps and Submit Version`

[image: Screenshot from iTunes connect]

I have referred to couple of answers on SO, but most of them are outdated(for iOS 3 and above), so I was wondering if Apple has revised the policy in recent days.

I use Xcode 7.3 on OS X 10.11

Comment: he cant compile the project in the sense?Did you send the build to him through testflight or through diawi or someother?

Comment: @Arun if he can't compile, there is no build to send via testflight or diawi or any other distribution mechanism.

Comment: I have a developer to assist me.

Answer (score 2):

On iTunesConnect manipulations only with app publishing.
What you might want, is to add him into your Team at [developer.apple.com/membercenter](http://developer.apple.com/membercenter).
Then developer via that site generates the Developer Certificate(s) and then creates Provision Profile via Xcode.

Comment: I have an individual developer account(not an enterprise account). I dont think we can add member in Member center for individual enrollment

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting this error due to missing provisioning profiles in your system. You can download the profiles linked to your account by doing the following steps:

1. Open `XCode`
2. Go to `Preferences`
3. Select your `Apple ID`. If not signed in, sign in to your individual Apple Developer Account
4. Select your `Team` from the right pane
5. Click `View Details`
6. Click `Download All`

Once all the profiles are downloaded, go to `Build Settings -> Code Signing` and choose the appropriate profiles for each.

In case you get an error again while building, do the following steps:

1. From your main machine (where you have been using your Developer account before), open `Keychain Access`
2. From the left pane, select `login`
3. Export the following to any location. It will be saved as a .p12 file. Give a password for them:

   - `iPhone Developer Certificate`
   - `iPhone Distribution Certificate`
4. Install these p12 files in your teammate's system.

You should be good to go now!